# Check if multiple values in table 1 are defined in table 2 with multiple values

Tags: sql, database, subquery

There are two tables: **CourseModules** and **Students**.

A student can participate in different modules. If a student succeed the module, it will be stored in the database under StudentsModule with the moduleID.

The table courseModules defines all required modules for a student to get a certificate.

I need an overview of all students that have an certificate.

In the example you can see that the only student that has a certificate is the one with **StudentID: 111221**

I am completely stuck on this. It needs to be done in one query, not multiple and without using loops.

[image: Database diagram overview]

I tried the following:

```
SELECT StudentID, ModuleID<br>
FROM StudentsModule<br>
WHERE ModuleID ALL (
    SELECT OnderdeelID
    FROM CourseModules 
    GROUP BY groupID
)
```

But i am stuck.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Please, not as a comment. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Done it now, im new to stack overflow. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select s.studentId, s.moduleId, cc.courseCount, cd.courseDone
from StudentsModule s
join CourseModulec on s.moduleId = c.moduleId
join (select count(*) as courseCount, groupId from CourseModule group by groupId) as cc on cc.groupId = c.groupId
join (select count(*) as courseDone, studentId from StudentsModule s1 join CourseModule c1 on s1.moduleId = c1.moduleId group by s1.studentId) as cd on cd.studentId = s.studentId
where cc.courseCount = cd.courseDone
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a step further. I got 3000 results now, i only needed to change a few things but you helped me out really well!

Many thanks!!!